# Change vertical position of strike-through?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, strikethrough

I'm applying the strikeout tag:

```
<s>$5,000,000</s>
```

But the line is too low.. .it's about 1/4 from the bottom rather than through the middle. Any way I can modify this so it goes a bit more through the middle?

Comment: strike is deprecated, css has `text-decoration:line-through;`

Comment: In an [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) document, for this text (a price that has been changed), [the `<s>` tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/s) is entirely appropriate, and more useful than inline CSS such as `<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">`. [The `<strike>` tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/strike) is indeed deprecated, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it with the strike tag OR the `text-decoration:line-through` style. The line position is built-in. You could roll your own style for that, but it would be a huge PITA.

Answer (score 9):

I've cooked up this code which gives you total control over strike-through position and style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css"> 

    .mark {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        top: -9px; /* Tweak this and the other top in equal, but opposite values */
        position: relative;
    }
    .offsetMark {
        position: relative;
        top: 9px; /* Tweak this and the other top in equal, but opposite values */
    }   

</style>     
</head>     
<body>        
<div>     
    <p class="strikethrough">This is an <span class="mark"><span class="offsetMark">example</span></span> of how I'd do it.</p>     
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quite the solution - just a bit too complex and messy so I won't bother applying it here. The line location seems fine on Windows machines. It's just mac machines that have something weird going on.

Comment: This has been a good help to bypass the Cufon text-decoration non-support.

Comment: In IE8 "Example" is chopped in half.  Only the top half of the text "example" is visible, then a solid line, then blank space.

Comment: IE8 is fine for me, but IE7 seems to ignore the positioning. I guess I could use it to fix firefox, which is what I came here for.

Comment: Also the line goes behind the text, which is relevant if you want the strike to have a different color.

Answer (score 4):

Eleven years later it is quite simple task:

```css
s{
  text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

s::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc( 50% - 1.5px );
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
old price: <s>$99.95</s>
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2024 Solution

Normally, you *would* use `text-decoration: line-through` to create a strike-through effect using CSS, but unfortunately, you can't change the vertical position of the strike line, so that's out.

Fortunately, you can create the same visual effect by with an **underline** (CSS: `text-decoration: underline`), because the CSS property [`text-underline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset) allows you to change the vertical position of the underline.

Here is how it works:

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: -.4em;
}
```

```html
<p>Only <span class="strike">$199.99</span> $99.99!</p>
```

### Hold up, that's kind of ugly.

Yeah, you may notice that the line seems a bit choppy. That's due to the relatively-new [`text-decoration-skip-ink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink) which tries to hide the underline in places where it would overwrite the text. It's great for underlining, but it fails as a strikethrough.

Luckily, we can turn that feature off, and along with some additional nice color and thickness properties, here's the final result:

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: -.4em;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>Only <span class="strike">$199.99</span> $99.99!</p>
```

Browser support is widespread with all current browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the strike tag, no. It's part of the rendering engine of the browser. For me (in Chrome) the line is rendered just above the middle.

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows for padding, and uses the csss line-through property
It works for firefox, and chrome/ safari does it right anyway.

---

```
div.hbPrice span.linethroughOuter {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    position: relative;
}
div.hbPrice span.linethroughInner {
    position: relative;
}
/* Firefox only. 1+ */
div.hbPrice span.linethroughOuter,  x:-moz-any-link  { bottom:  2px; }
div.hbPrice span.linethroughInner,  x:-moz-any-link  { top:  2px; }
```

and the mark up is something like...

```
<div class="hbPrice"><span class="linethroughOuter"><span class="linethroughInner">£1,998</span></span> £999</div>
```

The other solution is to add a background image of a line, and make it the same colour as the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="heading"><span>Test heading</span></div>

.heading {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.heading:before {
  background-color: #000000;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.heading span {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cLBls

Comment: Interesting, but has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution for one time usage...

```css
.strike {
  position: relative;
  right: 15px;
  top: -8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span>17<span class="strike">__</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```css
.strike{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.strike::after {
    background-color: #d90404;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 60%;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="strike">14.99</span> 9.99</p>
```