# Text-decoration line-through misaligned only on Safari/Mac

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to add a line-through, in all browsers it works fine, except Safari.

It gets misalignment.

[image: misalignment]

I'm not even using css, just an `s`tag inside the html

```
<span class="price--old">
 <s>{value}</s>
</span>
```

Comment: Safari on IOS for me with default font does not have this problem. In fact if you have lowercase text with descenders such as j g the line appears to look a bit high. What IS and font are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the `line through` and `del`
they both are't working in safari
I came up with an solution

```css
.price--old {
      width: 25px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .price--old::before {
      content: "";
      flex: 1 0 10px;
      border-top: 1px solid #111;
    }
    .old-price {
      margin-left: -25px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="price--old"><span class="old-price">200</span></div>
```

its working completely fine in `safari` and `chrome`

Answer (score 1):

Every browser interprets CSS differently. I *believe* the reason it's not working is because the `<s>` tag "renders a horizontal line through the vertical center of the text," so I assume it's finding an odd "vertical center."

[Per Apple's dev library:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html)

> s
>
> Deprecated. Defines a block of text in strikethrough style. Use del to indicate document edits.
>
> Discussion
>
> The content inside the s element is rendered with a horizontal line through the center. The del element is more appropriate to show text that was removed. Styles should be more finely tuned using CSS instead of using HTML style elements when possible.
>
> Availability
>
> The s element has been deprecated in the HTML 4.01 standard.

Try using the `<del>` tag instead

`<p>Let's try <del>this</del></p>`

And let me know if that doesn't work. It looks ok on my computer in Safari, but I have some weird settings on my Safari for a work project rn.

---

A little more research shows that there is a semantic difference between del and s: [What is the difference between <s> and <del> in HTML, and do they affect website rankings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743581/what-is-the-difference-between-s-and-del-in-html-and-do-they-affect-website)

> `<s>` and `<del>` both still exist in the HTML specification.
>
> ```
> The <del> element represents a removal from the document.
> The <s> represents contents that are no longer accurate or no longer relevant.
> ```
>
> That is to say that they actually represent different things
> semantically. Specifically  would be used if you had an existing
> document and wanted to indicate text that was in the document, but has
> been removed. This would be different than text in a document that is
> no longer accurate, but that has not been removed (you could use 
> for that).
>
> You should not use or depend on either for styling even though most
> browsers do have them strike-through by default. You should only rely
> on CSS for presentation.

Comment: Unfortunately neither with del nor just span applying a text-decoration, it doesn't work. I guess it's a expected behavior on Safari :(

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti Found this, it gives much more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215754/css-strike-through-not-centered-through-the-text